# Drawing Line, Arc etc. Anywhere in the Code Java

Tags: java, swing, drawing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am kind of newbie in Java and in my program, I have to draw some lines, arcs etc. in a function different from `paintComponent()` in some cases in a class that extends JPanel.

I generally work with ActionScript for visual stuff and I can draw any geometric figure in any functions when I work with AS.

So, is there way to do the same thing in Java, and how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- Why not draw in `paintComponent(...)`? You state your new, and perhaps you might misunderstand how to do Swing graphics best, so knowing your requirements and the rationale behind them can help us help you.
- You can draw on a BufferedImage at any time and in any code
- Then that image can be displayed either in a JComponent's `paintComponent(...)` method
- or in a JLabel's Icon via its `setIcon(...)` method.
- Be sure to read the Graphics2D API which will have all the methods needed to do your drawings.
- Be sure to read the Swing graphics tutorials because doing this type of work requires a paradigm shift.
- Do not get your Graphics object by calling `getGraphics()` on a component such as a JPanel. Either get it via calling `getGraphics()` on a BufferedImage or from the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` parameter.